# Strange behavior in SwiftUI: [App crashes when UITextField is focused?]

Tags: debugging, swiftui

Good morning,
In my production app I noticed what I think is a bug when altering a view (For example triggering a toggle) if a `UITextField` is `Focused` at the moment of altering the app will just crash. I'm able to reproduce this error. Is this supposed to be so? Do I really need to defensive develop this?

Basically I click on `AddCustomSource` and the textfield appears to add the custom source.
If I click on cancel or trigger one of the toggle while the textfield has focus, the app will just crash. 100% reproducible.

Here the error that the console shows:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to delete item containing first responder that refused to resign.
First responder that was asked to resign (returned YES from -resignFirstResponder): <UITextField: 0x13411bc00; frame = (0 0; 290 22); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002d66880>; placeholder = NewspaperTitle; borderStyle = None; background = <_UITextFieldNoBackgroundProvider: 0x6000021e5190: textfield=<UITextField 0x13411bc00>>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000023568e0>> inside containing view: <SwiftUI.ListCollectionViewCell: 0x134151a00; baseClass = UICollectionViewListCell; frame = (20 82.6667; 358 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000235d220>> at index path: <NSIndexPath: 0xae4395876dfb5f2e> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
Current first responder: <_TtGC7SwiftUI15CellHostingViewGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_14_ViewList_ViewVS_26CollectionViewCellModifier__: 0x134152000; frame = (0 0; 358 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002d62f70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000235dc20>> inside containing view: <SwiftUI.ListCollectionViewCell: 0x134151a00; baseClass = UICollectionViewListCell; frame = (20 82.6667; 358 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000235d220>> at index path: <NSIndexPath: 0xae4395876dfb5f2e> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.14 - Device: iPhone 14 Pro Max (9E3E3FA5-4FCC-47D7-9D91-E1E5E48286FE) - Runtime: iOS 16.2 (20C52) - DeviceType: iPhone 14 Pro Max
```

And here the code that leads to this behaviour:

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  BLE
//
//  Created by Entwicklung Help Tech GmbH on 22.12.22.
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreBluetooth



struct ContentView: View {
    @State var categories: [NewsSource] = []
    @State var isEditing = false
    @State var newSourceName = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($categories, id:\.self ) { $category in
                Section {
                    ForEach($category.sources, id: \.self ) { $source in
                        Toggle(source.name, isOn: $source.active)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .accessibilityLabel(String(localized: "s"))
                            .onChange(of: categories, perform: { newValue in
                                
                            })
                            .tint(Color.blue)
                        if !isEditing {
                            Button { [self] in
                                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                    isEditing.toggle()
                                }
                            } label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(String(localized:"AddCustomSource"))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            AddCell
                            HStack {
                                Button { [self] in
                                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                        //isFocused = false
                                        isEditing.toggle()
                                    }
                                } label: {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(String(localized: "Cancel"))
                                    }
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            header: {
                Text(category.name)
            }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            for index in 1...10 {
                categories.append(NewsSource(name: "\(index)", feeds: [NewsFeed(name: "News feed \(index)", url: URL(string: "https://google.de")!, active: true)]))
            }
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder var AddCell: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button { [self] in
                    if newSourceName != "" {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            isEditing.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .background(.green)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
                }
                TextField(String(localized: "NewspaperTitle"),text: $newSourceName)
                    .onSubmit { [self] in
                        if newSourceName != ""{
                            newSourceName = ""
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                isEditing.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    
    //
    //  Newspaper.swift
    //  Activator
    //
    //  Created by Entwicklung Help Tech GmbH on 20.02.23.
    //
    
    
    struct NewsSource: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable, Equatable {
        var id: UUID { UUID() }
        var name: String
        var sources: [NewsFeed]
        
        init(name: String, feeds: [NewsFeed]) {
            self.name = name
            self.sources = feeds
        }
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            self.sources = try container.decode([NewsFeed].self, forKey: .sources)
        }
        
        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(name)
        }
        
        static func ==(lhs: NewsSource, rhs: NewsSource) -> Bool {
            return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.sources == rhs.sources
        }
    }
    
    struct Newspaper: Codable, Hashable {
        var categories : [NewsSource]
    }
    
    struct NewsFeed: Codable, Equatable, Hashable, Identifiable {
        var id: UUID? {
            UUID()
        }
        
        let name: String
        let url: URL
        var active: Bool
        var image: String?
    }
```

Comment: Don't override `Mashable` and `Equatable` to only use the `name` when you edit the name the identity changes and everything gets redrawn. Keep the default implementations unless you have a really really good reason you can explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `id:\.self` everywhere, that's a mistake that causes crashes.

Comment: Got it. Will try it as soon as possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with iOS16. See https://openradar.appspot.com/FB11638212

The only present workaround I am aware of is to adding a [@FocusState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate) to your TextField and explicitly 'unfocussng' it prior to making the offending UI state change(s)